# A Woo commerce extension has deleted my old theme.How to undo?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I downloaded an shop extension from woocommerce and by mistake changed the whole theme to a shop theme. This wasn't my meaning. I worked alot on my old regular wordpress theme. Is there any way to undo ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it deletes your theme? It probably just change by another, go to **Appearance > Themes** (`/wp-admin/themes.php`) and check the installed themes, then activate the one that you really want.